# Oauth::timestamp refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, linkedin-api

i'm using linkedin gem for my RoR application, it's running fine on my local and stagign(it's live with dummy data only for testing) but on Production i'm having Oauth::timestamp refused error. My Staging and Production servers are using +0000 zone settings and i have no idea how to resolve this thing. Please let me know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can find out the current timestamp on the LinkedIn servers by sending a HEAD request for one of the resources.  In python this could be:

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("api.linkedin.com")
conn.request("HEAD", "/v1/people/~")
resp = conn.getresponse()
print resp.getheaders()
```

You could then use this date to set the date for your application for subsequent calls.  This is helpful when you don't have root access on the system (or know how to set the time/date)

Answer (score 0):

Your date on the server is likely incorrect.  You can read about the timestamp in the oauth specification [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.3).  It needs to be [within 5 minutes of LinkedIn's server time](https://developer.linkedin.com/comment/3198#comment-3198).

You can find it out by typing:

```
date
```

And set it by using:

```
date -s "17 Jan 2012 13:00:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your linked profile time zone and your rails app time zone configuration is not same. Check your linked in profile time zone what you have setted for your profile or may be location and set time by location on config/application.rb.

I just resolved this problem by set my time zone.